# Is this a useful wiki edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

A user [edited the empty wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/293463) for the [jnotify](/questions/tagged/jnotify) tag with only the following text:

> For more information see
>
> http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/

I'm tempted to reject it considering the fact that it is pretty useless since a simple google search would reveal exactly that and it doesn't contact any info about the tag. But I'm not sure whether I'm correct about this.

So: is this a valid wiki entry?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't agree with the "it's better than nothing" statement. We already tell people to "go read the tag wiki." So now they go read the tag wiki and it's only a link. Basically saying "ok, now go read this website."

A link-only tag wiki is just as bad as a link-only answer. It's not useful. **We want the information here.** I'd have no problem with *adding* a link to the official site if it wasn't there before, but *only* adding a link to an empty wiki just doesn't help anyone IMO. The key point here is that edit *creates a bad tag wiki* whereas adding a link to an existing one is *improving an already good tag wiki*.

Comment: +1. I'd have rejected it. Don't forget that the user gets +2 rep for that edit as well; is pasting a link in a text box really worthy of that?

Answer (score 7):

Your rejection would be invincible if after that, you'd edit tag wiki into something like:

> Find more information at http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/
>
> > JNotify is a java library that allows java application to listen to file system events, such as:
> >
> > - File created
> > - File modified
> > - File renamed
> > - File deleted
> >
> > #### Supported platforms
> >
> > - Windows (2000 or newer)
> > - Linux with INofity support (2.6.14 or newer) Linux notes
> > - Mac OS X (10.5 or newer) Mac OS notes
> >
> > #### Usage example
> >
> > JNotify can be tested by simply running the jar file with the followng command:
> >     **java -Djava.library.path=. -jar jnotify-VER.jar [dir]**
> >
> > JNotify will then monitor the specified dir (or the current directory if dir is not specified) and print detected events. Note
> >     that java.library.path should point to the location of the native
> >     libraries that comes with jnotify (dlls, so dylibs etc)...

<sub>Nothing really hard, just an abstract from the bare link provided at suggested edit.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's better than nothing in this case - and it's *possible* that a Google search sends you the wrong way to some other product named jNotify.

This is different from (completely useless) Wikipedia Copypasting IMO.

Comment: What did you do with Pekka? ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa Who cares? at prices like these, I'll take a Gucci handbag over Pekka, anyday! (genuine Gucci, of course... right?)

Comment: @PeeHaa you want bag? Is genuine.

Answer (score -1):

I agree that is not very useful. But I could not understand the problem with my edits [the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/568746) and [the second time](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/569058)

I might not be a very reputed user but I believe I am also a part of this community and my contributions would improve the community. Again, it is a "tag wiki" and users can keep on improving it. Still, it's not clear why my edits got rejected.

**I suggest reviewers should add more details about the rejection reason.**

Comment: The wiki should not just describe what is the product but also how it's related to Stack Overflow and what kind of questions are expected on this tag. For example the [tag:iphone] tag does not describe what iPhone is.

Comment: agree, but ms-word tag describes what is [Microsoft Word](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-word/info). My suggestion was reviewers should include details like why the edit is rejected and how the edit could have been improved.

Comment: No, this is same as leaving comment when downvoting. This is an option and should stay an option. If the reviewer wants to, he/she will leave a custom message. But they don't have to.